# Can we edit maxDepth in Firebase robotest. If yes, how?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I am trying to automate the "UI testing" for my android application by using firebase testlab. I have saved a script in android studio but want to limit the robot for any further monkey testing. All it does is after my sctipts runs successfully, it starts doing monkey testing, which is of no use to me.

I read it online it can be controlled using "maxDepth" but couldn't find anything more. Would appreciate if someone could help me implement this.

Answer (score 1):

maxDepth was only supported by Robo v1. It has been deprecated and has not had any effect on Robo tests for a long time.  The standard way to limit the length of a Robo test now is to use the timeout flag/option.

A possible(?) alternative would be to have your Robo script exit your app when it is done, but I have never tried that and am not sure how it would work.